# Can't assign pandas.shift() for specific rows in specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, html-table

[image: table as is => desired]

Hello, I'm fairly new to Python and I'm having problems with a table I scrapped using Selenium. Note: The table had merged rows, that's why I created column `'c'` as a copy of `'b'` for later treatment.

As you can see in the image, in certain rows ([2, 11, 15, 27]) the columns are shifted. **Basically what I need to do is to shift, in only those rows, the values in columns above `'d'` one cell to the left.**

I think I am pretty close to it, but I get an error. So far here's the code I have:

```
# Identify the rows to shift
list_channels = [str(row["a"]) for index, row in table.iterrows() if len(str(row["a"])) > 2 and str(row["a"])[2] == "-"]
rows_to_shift = table[table["a"].isin(list_channels)].index

# Assign shifted columns
table.iloc[rows_to_shift, 2:] = table.iloc[rows_to_shift, 2:].shift(-1, axis=1) # ValueError
```

What baffles me is that the right part of the assignation above (`table.iloc[rows_to_shift, 3:-1].shift(-1, axis=1)`) shows a 4-rows dataframe with indexes [2, 11, 15, 27] with columns ('d', :) in the layout I want, but when I make the assignation I get the error: *ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (4,28) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (4,1)*

Ok, now... here it gets a bit weird: That last assignation stopped the execution and showed me the error, but if I now print the table, it seems to be right (!?). The table was indeed modified and values are now where intended.

This script is intended for a high-profile group of users (high executives) so I cant just ignore the error and force the program to continue, because I can't risk that the script crashes when they use it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've been trying to solve this for days and I'm starting to go in circles.

EDIT: So I detected that this also gives an error: `table.iloc[rows_to_shift, 2:] = table.iloc[rows_to_shift, 2:]`, and now I'm completely hopeless.

Comment: Its just not possible for others to see the required detail in such an image. If you provided a (preferably simplified) example in code form that people can use without re-entering data then work on to demonstrate solutions then you are much more likely to get a helpful answer. You have to make it easy for people to respond to your question.

Comment: @user19077881 not sure if this is a serious comment but I'll answer... you can click on the image to enlarge it. And if you click on it again it will zoom in even further. 
In order to "make it easy for people to respond", I have created an image depicting starting point and expected result, highlighting the pertinent rows/columns. I also checked that the post displays OK and that text and image are readable. Besides, of course, of proper formatting and code labels in the text. A simplified table wasn't possible because the error did not happen with the dummy dataframes that I created.